# InputStream and OutputStream - How to differentiate ambiguity

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream

It seems to me that `InputStream` and `OutputStream` are ambiguous names for I/O.

`InputStream` can be thought of as "to input into a stream", and `OutputStream` can be thought of as "get output of a stream".

After all, we read from an "input" stream, but shouldn't you be reading from an "output"?

What was the rationale behind choosing these two names and what is a good way to remember Input/Output stream without confusing one for the other?

Comment: One simple way is to remember that you read from  `System.in` , and print to `System.out` .

Comment: There is no ambiguity. It is just named from your point of view. It is input to you, and output from someone else. Or output from you, and input to somebody else. Except, unfortunately, in `java.lang.Process`.

Comment: @EJP the ambiguity is that it's unclear whether the "input" stream means that im sending my input, or im receiving someone else's input. without a context, it's absolutely ambiguous

Comment: The so-called ambiguity is only whether it is your input or someone else's, and I have resolved that for you.

Comment: @EJP even from my point of view, an "input stream" can mean a stream that i input into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The streams are named not for how you use them inside your code but for what they **accomplish**. An `InputStream` accomplishes reading *input* from somewhere outside your program (the console, a file, etc.), whereas an `OutputStream` accomplishes writing an *output* to somewhere else (again, console, file, etc.). Your Java code is only the intermediary in this scenario: In order to make use of the input, you have to read it from the stream, and in order to produce an output, you first have to write something to the stream.

The problem with the naming is only that streams by design always have something that goes in and something that comes out - you can always read and write on/with any stream. All you have to remember is that they are named for the *more important task* they do: interacting with something outside your code.

Comment: it's probably for historical reasons, pertaining to I/O devices, that gave us these names, it's more intuitive when thinking about physical devices inputting data into a machine, and outputting data to devices.. now intuition is lost imo

Comment: If you think of your code as a "machine" and everything else as a "device", this is still true. It's just confusing because you have to *write* the *output* and *read* the *input* in your program.

Answer (score -1):

Think of your program/code as the **Actor**.

- When the **Actor** wants to read something in, it seeks an handle to
  InputStream cause its this stream that will provide the Input. And hence when you Read from it.
- When the **Actor** wants to write something out, it seeks an handle
  to OutputStream and then start writing to the handle which will do
  the rest. Likewise you Write to it.

I hope this answers. I just visualize my code as the classic Stick Diagram Actor and InputStream and OutputStream as the entities with which you interact.